# How to select set of data from a table from nth row to 1st row

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have written a query to select set of data from nth to last record like below

```
select station_code from route_master where route_code = "102D" and sequence_no limit "5", "100";
```

- table name: `route_master`
- column name: `route_code`

Now I want to select data from nth to 1st row.

Comment: Using `LIMIT` only really makes sense along with `ORDER BY`.  That being said, does your `route_master` table have a column which can be used for ordering?

Comment: yes.. i have sequence_no column is there

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a plain `LIMIT` command along with a subquery which imposes the reverse ordering:

```
SELECT station_code
FROM
(
    SELECT station_code, sequence_no
    FROM route_master
    WHERE route_code = '102D'
    ORDER BY sequence_no
    LIMIT n
) t
ORDER BY sequence_no DESC;
```